Group cross date range in SAS
I need to mash the range of dates that cross over in SAS.
For example:
ID  PROV    dt_entrata  dt_uscita   FLAG
381 00001   31/12/2004  09/11/2005  OK
381 00001   05/07/2011  16/04/2012  OK
**381   00001   31/12/2013  20/10/2014  KO
381 00001   19/10/2014  15/02/2018  KO**

It must become:
ID  PROV    dt_entrata  dt_uscita   FLAG
381 00001   31/12/2004  09/11/2005  OK
381 00001   05/07/2011  16/04/2012  OK
**381   00001   31/12/2013  15/02/2018  OK**


This method expands the ranges then regroups and collapses back to ranges.
data have;
   input ID $ PROV $ (dt_entrata dt_uscita)(:ddmmyy.)  FLAG $;
   cards;
381 00001   31/12/2004  09/11/2005  OK
381 00001   05/07/2011  16/04/2012  OK
381 00001   31/12/2013  20/10/2014  KO
381 00001   19/10/2014  15/02/2018  KO
;;;;
   run;
data havev / view=havev;
   set have;
   do date = dt_entrata to dt_uscita;
      output;
      end;
   drop dt_: flag;
   run;
proc sort data=havev out=exp nodupkey;
   by id prov date;
   run;

data expV / view=expV;
   set exp;
   by id prov;
   run + dif(date) ne 1;
   if first.prov then run=1;
   format date ddmmyy10.;
   run;
proc summary data=expv nway;
   by id prov;
   class run;
   output out=range(drop=_type_) min(date)=dt_entrata max(date)=dt_uscita;
   run;
proc print;
   run;



Perfect, thanks! I should union also range <=12 months. Have you got same ideas?

@Pier I do not understand the requirement.

You can avoid complicated logic within a by group by 'painting' date flags into temporary array and then finding the contiguous zones.
Example:
FLAG is also used to define a group in which crossover should be painted.
data have ; 
attrib id length=8 prov format=z5. dt_start dt_end informat=ddmmyy10. format=ddmmyy10. flag length=$2;
input 
ID  PROV    dt_start    dt_end      FLAG; datalines ;
381 00001   31/12/2004  09/11/2005  OK
381 00001   05/07/2011  16/04/2012  OK
381 00001   31/12/2013  20/10/2014  KO
381 00001   19/10/2014  15/02/2018  KO
;

data want ;
  array dates[ %sysevalf('01jan1990'd) : %sysevalf('31dec2050'd)] _temporary_ ;
  call missing (of dates(*)) ; 
  do until (last.FLAG) ;
    set have ;
    by id prov FLAG notsorted ;
    do index = dt_start to dt_end ; /* paint/fill */
      dates(index) = 1 ;
    end ;
  end ;

  call missing (dt_start, dt_end) ;
  do index = lbound(dates) to hbound(dates) ;
    if dates(index) and     missing (dt_start) then dt_start = index ; 
    if dates(index) and not missing (dt_start) then dt_end = index ;
    if missing(dates(index)) and nmiss(dt_start,dt_end) = 0 then do ;
      output ;
      call missing (dt_start, dt_end) ;
    end ;
  end ;
  drop index ;
run ;

You don't say anything about what should happen if FLAG differs within a crossover, so actual problem might by trickier.
